# TSQL GroupBy value every X seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @NUM AS INT   -- IT INDICATE THE NUMBER OF SECONDS TO GROUP THE DATA
DECLARE @DATA_START AS DATETIME = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @DATA_END AS DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT AVG(D.VALORE)
FROM AA_V_DATI_MISURAZIONE D
WHERE D.STARTDATE >= @DATA_START AND D.ENDDATE <= @DATA_END
```

Now I need to extra the average of `D.Valore` grouped by every `@NUM` seconds.

**Edit**: so this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DATA_START, D.DataOra) / @NUM, @DATA_START) AS DATAORA,
    AVG(D.Valore) AS MEDIAVALORE
FROM 
    AA_V_DatiMisurazione D 
WHERE 
    D.STARTDATE >= @DATA_START 
    AND D.STARTDATE <= @DATA_END 
GROUP BY 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DATA_START, D.DataOra) / @NUM
ORDER BY 
    DATAORA
```

Comment: What's what's stopping you? What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: *Assuming* SQL Server: [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: What is the problem with your current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the simpliest method would be to just use [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (assuming you are using the latest version of SQL Server, which you don't say you aren't):

```sql
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(SECOND, @NUM, STARTDATE) AS Second_Bucket,
       AVG(D.VALORE) AS AvgValore
FROM AA_V_DATI_MISURAZIONE D
WHERE D.STARTDATE >= @DATA_START AND D.ENDDATE <= @DATA_END
GROUP BY DATE_BUCKET(SECOND, @NUM, STARTDATE);
```

Note, however that for buckets that don't fit well into a minute, you might get undesired values. For example see the following:

```sql
DECLARE @DT datetime2(0) = '2023-07-01T00:00:04';
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(SECOND,7,@DT);
```

This results in the value `2023-06-30 23:59:58`. If you want the value taken from the *start* of the day, you could would need to pass a value for the function's 4th parameter, to define when a bucket starts. This might seem odd but use `DATE_BUCKET` again to truncate to the start of the date, as `DATE_BUCKET` requires the 3rd and 4th parameters have the same data type, and `DATE_BUCKET` retains the data type:

```sql
DECLARE @DT datetime2(0) = '2023-07-01T00:00:04';

SELECT DATE_BUCKET(SECOND,7,@DT, DATE_BUCKET(DAY,1,@dt));
```

This now returns `2023-07-01 00:00:00` and also means that the bucket that starts at `23:59:58` would only be for `23:59:58` and `23:59:59`.

---

If you are using an older version, you can use some `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` and integer math "magic":

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '20000101', STARTDATE) / @Num * @Num, '20000101') AS Second_Bucket,
       AVG(D.VALORE) AS AvgValore
FROM AA_V_DATI_MISURAZIONE D
WHERE D.STARTDATE >= @DATA_START AND D.ENDDATE <= @DATA_END
GROUP BY DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '20000101', STARTDATE) / @Num * @Num, '20000101');
```

This solution does not address the bucketing issue for buckets that don't "fit nicely". You could, however, achieve this why replacing the arbitrary date with your column `CAST`/`CONVERT`ed to a `date`.

Comment: i m using sql server 2016 so DATE_BUCKET is not available

Comment: That's information that should have been exposed in your qusetion, @bircastri .

Comment: What do you means with '20000101' ?

Comment: It's a date, @bircastri ... The 1st of January 2000.

Comment: I know that is a date. But ehy 1st of January 2000 ?

Comment: For the same reason use `1900-01-01` (`0`) in your attempt, @bircastri . If you want to use `1900-01-01` instead you could, however, I recommend against `0` as that won't work with any of the "new" date (and time) data types.

Comment: How would that round to the nearest, say, 5 seconds, @Charlieface ?

Comment: I admit, however, I could have used `DATETRUNC(DAY, @dt)` instead of `DATE_BUCKET(DAY,1,@dt)`, @Charlieface . My brain was just in "DATE_BUCKET mode" by that point.